# Flutter statusBar Color dependent on current Theme

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I make the color from my setSystemUIOverlayStyle dependent of the current theme mode?
I tried it with this:

```
bool isDarkModeOn(BuildContext context){
  final ThemeData mode = Theme.of(context);
  var whichMode=mode.brightness;
  if(whichMode == Brightness.dark){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

(Checking if darkmode is enable - Function works fine)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final systemThemeLight = SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
      systemNavigationBarColor:  const Color(0xdfd6f5ca),
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    );
        final systemThemeDark = SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
      systemNavigationBarColor:   Colors.black,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    );
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle( isDarkModeOn(context) ? systemThemeDark :  systemThemeLight);
```

The idea works, but only when I update the state by navigating to another screen, not by switching the Switch inside my App-settings.
Does anybody have a better idea?

Comment: It is because your build function is not getting called when you are using `switch`, For this to work you need the build to happen, try using `setState()` while toggling the `switch` this will force the build , then everything will work as expected

Comment: No doesn't changed it: `onTap: (value) {
                        Provider.of<ThemeService>(context, listen: false).toggleTheme();
                        setState(() {

                        });
                      }`
Same problem

Comment: I see that you are using provider. Try to listen to change and rebuild after toggle change this should solve your problem, try to force the widget to rebuild that's the only way it would work

Comment: I thought setState forces a rebuild? Yes, I use Provider and bloc.

Comment: If you are using blocbuilder , setstate can't be used, change the state ,.and listen for it , it will force rebuild, for me to giv proper input, i would be needing you to produce more code .

Comment: Tbh, I don't think it's a problem of not rebuilding the widget. When I change the Thememode and do a hot restart, (I thought this is also a method for forcing rebuilding the widget tree?), it still doesn't change the  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle. Only after a hot restart, it changes the Overlay style correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251157/discussion-between-fabian-m-and-krishna-acharya).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a Solution to this problem by myself, maybe it helps someone:

Wrap your scaffold above the bottomNavigatioBar:[...] with:

```
 return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: _currentStyle,
      child: Scaffold(
```

below Widget build function:

```
bool isDarkMode = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;
_changeColor(isDarkMode);
```

And inside Statefull widget:

```
SystemUiOverlayStyle _currentStyle = SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark;
  void _changeColor(bool isDarkMode) {
    setState(() {
      _currentStyle = SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
          systemNavigationBarColor: isDarkMode ? const Color(0xff272727) : Colors.grey[200]
      );
    });
  }
```

Then it changes automatically....